# Plotting lines within pirateplots?

Tags: r, plot

I am using pirateplot from the yarrr package to plot my data, similar to this example:

```
    pirateplot(formula = height ~ sex + headband + eyepatch,
        point.o = .1,
        data = pirates)
```

I would like to plot a line across each group to represent a parameter that is part of my paradigm. If I use `abline(h=155)`, the line is added to the last plot. How do I add a line to the first plot (at, say, 166)?

[image: pirateplot with line added at 155]

Comment: Be sure to clearly list any non-base R packages you are using.